# How to sort ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String,String>> by key?

Tags: java, android

I am building a recipe searching app which takes recipe data from a website and displays it on the results page of the app (it's using JSON). I looked at tutorials on the web and found that a HashMap within an ArrayList was common for this sort of feature and I used a LinkedHashMap instead as I was interested in the insertion order.

The results of the information display fine on the recipe page. As my recipe page can have over 20+ recipes (depending on the search terms used), I want to give the user the option to resort the results list with the click of a button.

[image]

Here is a fragment of how I am populating my arraylist.

```
static ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String,String>> pairs = new ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String,String>>();  
LinkedHashMap<String, String> map;

for (i=0; i<matches.length(); i++){
map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

map.put("id", id);
map.put("name", name);
map.put("rating", rating);
map.put("source", source);
pairs.add(map);
}
```

Below is an example of my arraylist (printed out)

```
{id=1518539, name=Slow Cooker Mac and Cheese, rating=4, source=Merlot Mommy}
{id=1522143, name=Crock Pot Chicken Stroganoff, rating=4, source=Diethood}
{id=1506448, name=Slow Cooker Lemon-Garlic Chicken, rating=4, source=Magic Skillet}
{id=1520809, name=Chicken Tortilla Soup, rating=4, source=How does your garden grow}
```

Here is my actionbar `onOptionsItemSelected` method

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.a_z:
                //sort recipe name alphabetically
            case R.id.z_a:
                //sort recipe name reverse alphabetically

            case R.id.by_rating:
                //sort rating by highest values

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
```

So, how do I go about sorting this list, let's say alphabetically as an example.

Comment: Why are you storing this in a `Map` instead of a class with `name`, `id`, `rating`, and `source` fields?  That makes everything much more difficult, less efficient, and is just generally bad practice.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I just used some tutorials to do most of this so I wasn't sure what the correct way of doing this was

Answer (score 0):

As @LouisWasserman said, you should have a class rather than a map.  But the answer is you can use Collections.sort, with a custom Comparator.  Different Comparator classes-  1 for each mode.  For example, the two name ones can just chain to a string comparator that compares their names.

Answer (score 0):

> A better solution for this problem you can do for your project is.

Just make a class name `Student`. Just for your reference.

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;

public class Student implements Comparable<Student>{
    private int id;
    private String name;

public Student(int id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}
    public static final Comparator<Student> NameComparator = new Comparator<Student>(){

        @Override
        public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
            return o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
        }

    };

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" + "id=" + id + ", name=" + name +'}';

    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Student other = (Student) obj;
        if (this.id != other.id) {
            return false;
        }
        if ((this.name == null) ? (other.name != null) : !this.name.equals(other.name)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        hash = 47 * hash + this.id;
        hash = 47 * hash + (this.name != null ? this.name.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

}
```

Now here i am writing a `Student Class` to show that how this **customized** **sorting** will perform. and result will be shown :==>

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class StudentSortingTest {

    public void testSorting(){

        Student s1 = new Student(1, "Saurabh");
        Student s2 = new Student(2, "Vikrant");
        Student s3 = new Student(3, "Bhushan");
        Student s4 = new Student(4, "Neeraj");
        Student s5 = new Student(5, "Awasthi");


    List<Student> obj_ListStudent = new ArrayList<Student>();
        obj_ListStudent .add(s1);
        obj_ListStudent .add(s2);
        obj_ListStudent .add(s3);
        obj_ListStudent .add(s4);
        obj_ListStudent .add(s5);

         //print List before Sorting.
       this.printList(obj_ListStudent);
         //perform customized Sorting using Collections Class.
       Collections.sort(obj_ListStudent);
          //print List After Sorting.
       this.printList(obj_ListStudent);
    }

    public void printList(ArrayList<Student> list){ //Print elements of Student.
    for(Student elem : list){
        System.out.println(elem+"  ");
    }

    public static void maint(String... args){ //Main Method.

    StudentSortingTest obj = new StudentSortingTest();
    obj.testSorting();

     }

}
```

> **Note** :==> This Might helpfull for you to do customized Sorting and may easier to implement your own **Customized** `Class`